# Editing profile on meta

Tags: support, profile-page

I cannot edit my profile on the Ask different Meta.

I had an issue ([posted on Stackexchange meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114958/merged-accounts-and-have-now-lost-over-600-rep)) with merged accounts and loss of info and rep. This has now been fixed.

I am now having an issue where I have edited my profile and clicked 'Copy profile to all stack exchange accounts'

This did not copy to the Ask different meta, nor can I edit the account on here.

Is this a bug many people are having or is it just my profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta is synced with the main site every hour, and cannot be edited from meta itself. The copy profile will update your primary site profile, and then this will be synced with Meta at the next sync.

The only exception is Meta.SO which is not linked to SO in the same way. Currently both your profiles are showing the same information.

Comment: I did check back and saw that the Meta info had changed, this answers why it did not change like the others, and also why it changed when I revisited, Thanks